# Using 3dplot package in Lyx

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx

I'm trying to get the following `tikz` code to run with LyX:
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/the-3dplot-package/

My preamble contains:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf}
```

I removed the `\documentclass{article}` and `\begin{document}` and put the `3dplot.sty` in the same directory as my `*.lyx` file. I put the rest of the code between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document`} in the ERT mode.

I keep getting plenty of error messages:

[image]

Comment: I could compile the .tex file on the command line but when I imported it into LyX, compilation gave me an error. This could be a bug in LyX. Could you please report this at http://www.lyx.org/trac and choose component "tex2lyx" ?

Comment: thanks @scottkosty, I reported this: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9480